# How to detect second occurrence of an empty line in a text file?

Tags: php

I have a text file with few empty lines but not continuously. I have to detect the second occurring empty line in the text file. The contents of the file will be as follows:

```
item1

item2

item3
item4
item5
item6

item7
```

I want to detect the second empty line to read data from `item3`. Please help me with the code.

Comment: Where is the code that we should help you with?

Comment: foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if ('' === trim($value)) {
        $empty1 = $value ;
    }
} using this to detect 1st empty line

Comment: So increment a simple counter then, every time you encounter an empty row … and check the value of that counter and do whatever you need to, when it reaches two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $arr is the lines of the file...

```
$emptyLinesSkipped = 0;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
  if ('' === trim($value)) {
    if ($emptyLinesSkipped < 2) {
      $emptyLinesSkipped = $emptyLinesSkipped + 1;
      continue;
    }

    $item3 = $value;
    // and so on...
  }
}
```